# Installing a new DB2 subsystem at function level 100 (z/OS)

Tags: db2, zos, db2-zos

Apologies, if this is a newb question; I'm hoping there are some DB2 gurus that may be able to shed some light on this for me.

We are creating a new DB2 subsystem (on z/OS), modeling from an existing one. The existing one was migrated to DB2 12 and is still at function level 100.

```
CATALOG LEVEL (V12R1M500 ) 
CODE LEVEL (V12R1M505 )            
CURRENT FUNCTION LEVEL (V12R1M100 )
```

While going through the install panels, for the new subsystem, I am unable to specify `V12R1M100` for the target function level. It wants `V12R1M500`, and after doing some reading, it appears that an install requires an activation at function level 500.

Is this true? Or, is it possible to install a new subsystem at function level 100? My  guess is that it is. So, my second question would be: how difficult would it be? Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know this for sure for new installs, but M100 is basically the old "Conversion Mode" from before version 12. This was basically just a way during the upgrade process to land in the new "binaries", but still be able to fall back into the old version (v11 in the case of V12R1M100) if something tragic happened. It would make sense to me that it would not be an option to install M100 on a new subsystem.

Comment: @bhamby, I think you're right, the more I look into it. I appreciate the response!